# Determine if the protected view options are active within the document

Tags: excel, vba, protected

At the time of opening a document, it indicates to view it I must enable editing of the protected view.

I want at the time it is detected, to close the document until deleting that configuration of Excel.

[image]

Is there any small VBA function that does this procedure?

> error 91 occurred at variable object runtime with block not set

```vb
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.Quit
Else
End If
```

The entire ActiveWorbook code

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim hoja As Worksheet

    For Each hoja In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        hoja.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next hoja

    If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Application.Quit
    Else
    End If

    If Not VBATrusted() Then
        Application.Visible = False
        MsgBox "Aviso. Ya no puedes usar este archivo. Comunícate con el desarrollador Arq. Luis Eduardo Ramírez Aguayo entremuros.masterplan@hotmail.com Cel. +(52) 415.151.102"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Application.Quit
    End If

    Sheets("Hoja1").Visible = xlVeryHidden

    '----------------------------------------------------------------'

    Application.Visible = False

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim hoja As Worksheet

    Sheets("Hoja1").Visible = xlSheetVisible

    For Each hoja In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If hoja.Name <> "Hoja1" Then
            hoja.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next hoja

    '----------------------------------------------------------------'

    Sheets("HojaEscondida").Range("A4") = "admin"
    Sheets("HojaEscondida").Range("A4") = "admin"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        MsgBox "NO SE PUEDE GUARDAR COMO." & Chr(10) _
          & "Guarde el original, usando el icono guardar," & Chr(10) _
          & "o simplemente use la x de cerrar, y se guardará" & Chr(10) _
          & "automáticamente en el lugar correcto", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub


Function VBATrusted() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    VBATrusted = (Application.VBE.VBProjects.Count) > 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

1. Click File > Options.
2. Click Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View.
3. Uncheck Enable Protected View for files originating from the internet.

Hope it helps

Comment: The idea is to do it through VBA

Comment: @EduardoGonzalez Protected View is a security feature that disables macros and editing of the file. If you could run VBA code in the protected view this would be a securtity hole. Therefore you cannot run any code in protected view.

Comment: Any how, you mentioned that this excel files are coming from your email. Depends on your version, you can just enable the excel files that comes from Outlook.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego you are right but I think he sends the file to other persons (*"I am sending the document by mail"*) so the person who recieves the mail would need to enabele that (which is hopefully restricted by the companies group policy).

Answer (score 0):

Protected View is a security feature that disables macros and editing of the file. If you could run VBA code in the protected view this would be a securtity hole. Therefore you cannot run any code in protected view.

As a workaround you can add a worksheet `ProtectionInfo` and write some warning message on in like *"This workbook needs to be opened with macros enabled and without protected view!"*

Then you write a code in your `Workbook_Open` which hides the worksheet `ProtectionInfo` if the workbook opens. That means if macros are enabled and the user is not in protected view he will not see the warning worksheet. But if macros are disabled or in protected view, the user will see the warning.

Make sure to make the worksheet `ProtectionInfo` visible on `Workbook_BeforeClose` so it is shown again next time anyone opens it with macros disabled. Additionally you might want to hide all other worksheet so `ProtectionInfo` is the only worksheet that is shown when macros are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pᴇʜ said, you can only do a workaround by hiding all Worksheets except one where it says you have to disable protected view and unhide the worksheets when macros are enabled. But you should do that at `Workbook_BeforeSave` because some people save it in between but don't save it in the end and then the worksheets wouldn't be hidden then next time it's opened.

Since I already made that for myself for when macros are disabled with notification, I can share it here.
The following code will hide all worksheets except "No Macros" where I have a message shown how to enable macros.
Notice that I added a Variable LastSheet so when someone saves the file that it knows where to jump back to after it has unhidden all worksheets again

```
Dim LastSheet As String

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Unhide_Worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    LastSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
    Hide_Worksheets
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Unhide_Worksheets
End Sub

Private Sub Hide_Worksheets()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("No Macros").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("No Macros").Activate

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Worksheet.Name <> "No Macros" Then
            Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next Worksheet
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Unhide_Worksheets()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False        
    On Error Resume Next        
    For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next Worksheet
    On Error GoTo 0

    If LastSheet <> vbNullString Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LastSheet).Activate
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("No Macros").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```